# Get movies in order of maximum common genres, then keywords

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table Movies:

```
id    |                  title                           |    year 
315      Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2         2011
407      Cinderella                                           2015
826      The Shape of Water                                   2017
799      Enchanted                                            2007
523      How to Train Your Dragon                             2010
618      Crazy Rich Asians                                    2018
```

and the table Genres:

```
movie_id   |    genre
315             adventure
315             fantasy
315             mystery
315             drama
407             drama
407             fantasy
826             drama
826             thriller
826             adventure
826             horror
799             fantasy
799             comedy
799             romance
523             drama
523             fantasy
618             romance
618             comedy
```

and the table keyword:

```
movie_id     |       keyword 
315                  magic
315                  wizards
315                  witch
315                  friendship
315                  abuse 
407                  prince 
407                  fairy tale
407                  magic
407                  poor girl
407                  abuse 
826                  scientist
826                  mute
826                  friendship
799                  musical
799                  magic
799                  witch
799                  friendship
523                  viking
523                  boy
523                  fire
618                  singapore
618                  wedding
618                  money
```

I am trying to construct a query which outputs all the movies which have genres in common to a given movie. If there are movies which have the same number of common genres, then I want to rank those movies by the order of maximum common keywords.

E.g. If the movie was 'Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2', then the output of the query would be:

```
title                      |      genre_frequency     |    keyword_frequency
Cinderella                        2                        2
The Shape of Water                2                        1
How to Train Your Dragon          2                        0
Enchanted                         1                        3
```

Movies that don't have any genres that are common with the specified movie are not included in the output (e.g. Crazy Rich Asians).

I have two queries that can give me the genre_frequency and keyword_frequency.

```
select m.*, genre_frequency from movie m
join (
     select m.id, count(*) as genre_frequency
     from movie m
     join genre g on m.id=g.movie_id
     where g.genre in (select g1.genre 
                       from genre g1
                       where g1.movie_id=315)
     group by m.id
     ) f
 on m.id=f.id
 where m <> 315
 order by f.genre_frequency desc;


select m.*, keyword_frequency from movie m
join (
     select m.id, count(*) as keyword_frequency
     from movie m
     join keyword k on m.id=k.movie_id
     where k.keyword in (select k1.keyword
                       from keyword k1
                       where k1.movie_id=315)
     group by m.id
     ) f
 on m.id=f.id
 where m <> 315
 order by f.keyword_frequency desc;
```

The problem is that I want to combine the two queries above into a single query so that I can the output table as seen above. I am not sure how I can do this. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `UNION ALL` combine `Genres` and `keyword` tables and add `grp` column to split two part for the result set. then use condition aggregate function.

**Query #1**

```
select m.title, 
      count(CASE WHEN t1.grp = 'g' THEN 1 END) as genre_frequency,
      count(CASE WHEN t1.grp = 'k' THEN 1 END) as keyword_frequency
from Movies m
join (
    SELECT movie_id,genre name,'g' grp
    FROM Genres 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT movie_id,keyword,'k' grp
    FROM keyword
) t1 on m.id=t1.movie_id
where (t1.name in (select g1.genre 
               from Genres g1
               where g1.movie_id=315) or 
      t1.name in (select k1.keyword 
               from keyword k1
               where k1.movie_id=315)) 
AND m.id <> 315
group by m.title;

| title                    | genre_frequency | keyword_frequency |
| ------------------------ | --------------- | ----------------- |
| Cinderella               | 2               | 2                 |
| Enchanted                | 1               | 3                 |
| How to Train Your Dragon | 2               | 0                 |
| The Shape of Water       | 2               | 1                 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kQAoXLHCV9Ffoca6cSW9VQ/0)

Comment: What do the lines 'count(CASE WHEN t1.grp = 'g' THEN 1 END) as genre_frequency, count(CASE WHEN t1.grp = 'k' THEN 1 END) as keyword_frequency' do?

Comment: This is condition aggregate function. `Count` with `Case when`

Comment: I am not sure what t1.grp = 'g' and t1.grp = 'k' means within the condition aggregate function.

Comment: @D-Shih . . . The `where` is not really needed.  You could use `having genre_frequency > 0 or keyword_frequency  > 0` instead.

Comment: I tried the above query with the same tables, however I am getting an error "column t1.name does not exist, LINE 12: where (t1.name in (select g1.genre". I think this is because the table t1 that results from the join does not have an attribute called 'name'. Is there any way I can get the above code to work? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the query below first get all movies and inner join with the movies that had genres in common with the movie you are looking for. this will allow to get rid of any movies without any genres in common with the movie to be searched on.

I am using your query for genre frequency as a derived table in this case. I also removed the IN clause in the where statement and used another inner join for better performance.

the second derived table, the one joined using LEFT JOIN is the query you used to get the keyword frequency. same logic applies as the genre frequency table, the only difference is the LEFT JOIN since two movies can have genres in common but not keywords.

notice the IFNULL statement in the select clause so that we return 0 if no keywords found that are common.

at the end, we just sort first by genre frequency and then keyword frequency, in descending order.

```
select m.title, IFNULL(g_fq.genre_frequency,0), 
IFNULL(k_fq.keyword_frequency,0)
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN 
(select m.id as movie_id, genre_frequency from movie m
join (
     select m.id, count(*) as genre_frequency
     from movie m
     join genre g on m.id=g.movie_id
     INNER JOIN 
       (select g1.genre 
       from genre g1
       where g1.movie_id=315) as a on a.genre=g.genre
     group by m.id
     ) f
 on m.id=f.id
 where m.id <> 315
 ) as g_fq ON m.id=g_fq.movie_id

 LEFT JOIN 
 (
select m.id as movie_id, keyword_frequency from movie m
join (
     select m.id, count(*) as keyword_frequency
     from movie m
     join keyword k on m.id=k.movie_id
     INNER JOIN
      (select k1.keyword
       from keyword k1
       where k1.movie_id=315) as b on b.keyword=k.keyword
     group by m.id
     ) f
 on m.id=f.id
 where m.id <> 315
 ) as k_fq on m.id=k_fq.movie_id
 order by IFNULL(g_fq.genre_frequency,0) DESC,IFNULL(k_fq.keyword_frequency,0) DESC
```